# What happens with recaptcha registration when google account is removed?

Tags: recaptcha, google-account, recaptcha-v3

Our college has recaptcha v3 registered for company domain on his google account. He will go away soon. If his google accont will be removed or disactivated, is our recaptcha going to stop to work?

Answer (score 0):

reCaptcha will continue to work as long as your site key is active.   If your site key is disabled, reCaptcha will stop working until you re-activate or change the key.

[According to Google](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32046?hl=en), when an account is deleted, "You’ll lose all the data and content in that account"

Since reCaptcha is a Google service under an account, I would assume this means that google will delete your site key, as such your reCaptcha will stop working until you create a new key and change your code to include the new key.